# Can you play a List<Song> continuously in the background on Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, media-player

I have a list of songs `(List<Song>)` and i want to play all the songs even if the application goes into the background or under the lock screen.

I cannot use a `SongCollection` and `MediaPlayer.Play(SongCollection)` because i cannot create a `SongCollection` object from a `List<Song>`.

Is there anyway i can play this list of songs in the background, one by one (MediaPlayer.Play()) or otherwise?

Comment: you can use `MediaLibraryExtensions` to add songs to the SongCollection http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.media.phoneextensions.medialibraryextensions_members%28v=xnagamestudio.42%29.aspx

Comment: if you are referring to the SaveSong method, it does not help, because this method saves the song into a MediaLibrary. I'm trying to develop an music player application that uses the Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media. My issue is that my custom playlists that are constructed by putting the selected <Song> objects (objects that are taken from the ML) from a <LongList> into a List<Song> cannot play all the songs in the created playlists if the app goes into the background I cannot use a SongCollection object and add Song objects to it because it does not have a constructor, i'm missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is right in the documentation for SongCollection class: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.media.songcollection.aspx

> All of the collections, playlists, and queues returned by methods and
>   properties in the Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media namespace are
>   immutable. You cannot add or remove objects from those collections or
>   playlists. To create a custom 'playlist' of songs, games must maintain
>   their own list of songs to play, and play those songs one at a time by
>   calling MediaPlayer.Play.

The only thing you might be able to do is add a background audio agent to your app. More details on that here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202978(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: Sadly i knew this answer, i was hoping someone found other ways or workaround this limitation. Regarding the Background Agent it can only play files from iso storage or from a remote URI. So i cannot work with Song Objects and BackgroundAudioPlayer unless i copy all the phone's songs into the isolated storage which is not acceptable, or found a way to extract the URI from the Song object which again is not possible or at least i didn't find a way until now. I think i have to drop making a Media Player App using XNA.Framework.Media, its just too limited. Many thanks for your reaction though!