# Windows phone 8: how to play background next song?

Tags: windows-phone-8, audio-player, background-music

I'm programming an app which is able to play music in background. I'm using mediaplayer and Song(class xnalib), well since is not possible put file into mediaplayer.queue I can't figure out how can play next song in the "playlist".
I'll try to make this scenario more clear with an example:

- I play music with mediaplayer: MediaPlayer.Play(MysongArray[CurrentIndex]);
- well now user put my app in background.
- but when MysongArray[CurrentIndex] song is ended how play next song if my application is in background?

thanks

Comment: Have you considered using BackgroundAudio?: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202978(v=vs.105).aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394039(v=vs.105).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's probably because you are playing a `Song` not a `SongCollection` - once it's ended it stops playing. Source: [MSDN1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.media.mediaplayer.play.aspx), [MSDN2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.media.mediaplayer.aspx). I belive (thounght I've not tried it) that you should create SongCollection ([if it's possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20363269/can-you-play-a-listsong-continuously-in-the-background-on-windows-phone-8)) or [Manage existing one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.media.phoneextensions.medialibraryextensions_members%28v=xnagamestudio.42%29.aspx). But this can be a hard job as @ToniPetrina [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15021884/2681948).
As for me I would consider using [Background Audio Player](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394039(v=vs.105).aspx) and [How to play](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202978(v=vs.105).aspx).
Maybe this will help if you decide to use BAP - [example how to use playlist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19946512/how-to-select-a-song-from-playlist-in-background-audio-player/19947076#19947076).

Comment: that you should create SongCollection (if it's possible): no it's impossible :)

Comment: @LXG So if you need custom playlists BAP can be better. But it doesn't have access to MediaLib and as ToniPetrina said below - it can play only from IsolatedStorage and Web.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that since background player can only stream or play from isolated storage. You cannot play songs from MediaLibrary.

Comment: No I'm not intend to use Background player I'm using mediaplayer